# Programming an RSTP server to send RTP to a 3rd party

Tags: c++, api, video, rtsp, rtp

I'm writing a server application in C++ that needs to talk to an RTSP server.

Clients will connect to my server application and my application will talk to the RTSP server telling it "Send RTP stream X from your port A to client port B on IP 1.2.3.4 using H.264 encoding".

I started to look for an RTSP tutorial, but most examples just involve a client requesting a URI like rtsp://example.com/media.mp4. I also looked at RFC 2326, but found it quite hard to digest.

Does anybody know a good RTSP tutorial or book ?
Maybe some sample code solving a similar problem or a C++ library that implements RTSP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a private API i'm not aware of to control the RTSP server, you can't do what you are asking.
What you could do is ask the RTSP server to send to your server the specified stream and forward it to the client.
To comnunicate easily with an rtsp server, you can use gstreamer : http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/

Comment: Using a standard API would be better, but are you aware of a RTSP server for Windows that has such a private API ?

Comment: Vincent, you should really not try to do it this way (and you can't because of SDP negociation process and RTP being really a mess in NAT configurations if you don't let the client initiate the negociation).
What you should do is send to the client a rtsp URI where it will connect by itelf.

Comment: There will be a negotiation of the desired format etc. between my server and the client, but the actual RTP handling is to be handled by the RTSP server.